# Collectionview cells won't render with CKAsset

Tags: ios8, uicollectionview, cloudkit

I'm no longer able to render collectionview cells after using data from Cloudkit via CKAssets. I was previously using images loaded in a folder on my desktop just for initial testing. I'm now using Cloudkit and I've created some test records via the CK dashboard using those same images. I was successfully able to query the CK database and retrieve the expected records. I then changed my code to populate the model data for the cells to use the CK data. That data previously came from the images retrieved locally. I can see from logging that I am getting the data from CK successfully, including the images. I can also see from logging that my custom CV cells are no longer getting initialed. From what I can tell, my code looks good based on examples I've seen online.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Designated initializer in the model...

```
- (instancetype)initImagesForSelection:(NSString *)selectionType {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ImageDescription = 'description'"];
        CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"ImageData" predicate:predicate];

        [publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
            // handle the error
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: there was an error querying the cloud... %@", error);
            } else {
                // any results?
                if ([results count] > 0) {
                    NSLog(@"Success querying the cloud for %lu results!!!", (unsigned long)[results count]);
                    for (CKRecord *record in results) {
                        ImageData *imageData = [[ImageData alloc] init];
                        CKAsset *imageAsset = record[@"Image"];
                        imageData.imageURL = imageAsset.fileURL;
                        NSLog(@"asset URL: %@", imageData.imageURL);
                        imageData.imageName = record[@"ImageName"];
                        //imageData.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageAsset.fileURL]];
                        imageData.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageAsset.fileURL.path];
                        NSLog(@"image size height:%f, width:%f", imageData.image.size.height, imageData.image.size.width);
                        [self.imageDataArray addObject:imageData];
                    }
                    NSLog(@"imageDataArray size %lu", (unsigned long)[self.imageDataArray count]);
                }
            }
        }];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Collectionview viewcontroller which worked perfectly before pulling the data from Cloudkit...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; // string value identifier for cell reuse
    ImageViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"cellForItemAtIndexPath: section:%ld row:%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

    ImageData *imageData = [self.imageLoadManager imageDataForCell:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.image = imageData.image;

    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out. My code was actually working. The collectionview was not displaying due to a multithreading/asynchronous download issue with the data from cloudkit. I hit the camera button to take a pic, which refreshed the CV and everything in the CV appeared. I just need to use multithreading so things start rendering while the images are downloading.